# How to access the output of a function in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, google-sheets, next.js, vercel

I'm trying to make a website with Vercel with Next.js. I started with a Next.js template.

I have a function that gets strings from a Google Sheets sheet. That part was actually working, I just don't know how to get the output of the function into the page. I think it could be something to do with it being an async function, or something to do with which directory the file is in.

In the code below, the line where I have `const print_var='test';` I want to put `col1` in instead of `test`.

Here's the `page.tsx` file:

```
// 'use client'
// import React from 'react';
import { getDataFromGoogleSheet } from '../pages/google_access';
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';

interface HomeProps {
  col1: string | null;
  col2: string | null;
  col3: string | null;
}

export async function load() {
  try {
    const { props } = await getDataFromGoogleSheet({ row: 1, column: 1 });

    return {
      props: {
        col1: props.data[0],
        col2: props.data[1],
        col3: props.data[2],
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    return {
      props: {
        col1: null,
        col2: null,
        col3: null,
      },
    };
  }
}


export default function Home({ }) {

  const print_var='test';

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <div className="z-10 max-w-5xl w-full items-center justify-between font-semibold text-5xl lg:flex">
        <p className="fixed left-0 top-0 flex w-full justify-center border-b border-gray-300 bg-gradient-to-b from-zinc-200 pb-6 pt-8 backdrop-blur-2xl dark:border-neutral-800 dark:bg-zinc-800/30 dark:from-inherit lg:static lg:w-auto  lg:rounded-xl lg:border lg:bg-gray-200 lg:p-4 lg:dark:bg-zinc-800/30">
          {print_var}, Sand, Lime&nbsp;

        </p>
        <div className="fixed bottom-0 left-0 flex h-48 w-full items-end justify-center bg-gradient-to-t from-white via-white dark:from-black dark:via-black lg:static lg:h-auto lg:w-auto lg:bg-none">
          <a
            className="pointer-events-none flex place-items-center gap-2 p-8 lg:pointer-events-auto lg:p-0"
            href="https://vercel.com?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=appdir-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >


          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="relative flex place-items-center before:absolute before:h-[300px] before:w-[480px] before:-translate-x-1/2 before:rounded-full before:bg-gradient-radial before:from-white before:to-transparent before:blur-2xl before:content-[''] after:absolute after:-z-20 after:h-[180px] after:w-[240px] after:translate-x-1/3 after:bg-gradient-conic after:from-sky-200 after:via-blue-200 after:blur-2xl after:content-[''] before:dark:bg-gradient-to-br before:dark:from-transparent before:dark:to-blue-700 before:dark:opacity-10 after:dark:from-sky-900 after:dark:via-[#0141ff] after:dark:opacity-40 before:lg:h-[360px] z-[-1]">
        <p className={`m-0 max-w-[30ch] text-sm opacity-50`}>
          Can you think of a word that you can combine with each of the three words to create three new words or
          phrases?
          <br/>
          <br/>
          Here is an example: sand, age, and mile; the answer is stone (stone age, sandstone, milestone).
          <br/>
          <br/>
          Don't try too hard! These puzzles are best solved by not concentrating, and instead letting the answer come to you. Check
          the past CRA puzzles for examples and see the answer tomorrow.
          <br/>
          <br/>
          Try a new CRA puzzle every day to exercise your creative mind.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div className="mb-32 grid text-center lg:max-w-5xl lg:w-full lg:mb-0 lg:grid-cols-4 lg:text-left">
        <a
          href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Associates_Test#Compound_Remote_Associates_Test"
          className="group rounded-lg border border-transparent px-5 py-4 transition-colors hover:border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:dark:border-neutral-700 hover:dark:bg-neutral-800/30"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          <h2 className={`mb-3 text-2xl font-semibold`}>
            CRA Puzzles{' '}
            <span className="inline-block transition-transform group-hover:translate-x-1 motion-reduce:transform-none">
              -&gt;
            </span>
          </h2>
          <p className={`m-0 max-w-[30ch] text-sm opacity-50`}>
            Compound Remote Associate (CRA) puzzles are used in cognition and psychology research. Find out more here.
          </p>
        </a>

        <a
          href="https://www.smbc-comics.com/"
          className="group rounded-lg border border-transparent px-5 py-4 transition-colors hover:border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:dark:border-neutral-700 hover:dark:bg-neutral-800/30"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          <h2 className={`mb-3 text-2xl font-semibold`}>
            Contact{' '}
            <span className="inline-block transition-transform group-hover:translate-x-1 motion-reduce:transform-none">
              -&gt;
            </span>
          </h2>
          <p className={`m-0 max-w-[30ch] text-sm opacity-50`}>
            Tell me what you think about CRA Puzzles!
          </p>
        </a>

        <a
          href="https://www.crapuzzle.xyz/past-cra-puzzles"
          className="group rounded-lg border border-transparent px-5 py-4 transition-colors hover:border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:dark:border-neutral-700 hover:dark:bg-neutral-800/30"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          <h2 className={`mb-3 text-2xl font-semibold`}>
            Past puzzles{' '}
            <span className="inline-block transition-transform group-hover:translate-x-1 motion-reduce:transform-none">
              -&gt;
            </span>
          </h2>
          <p className={`m-0 max-w-[30ch] text-sm opacity-50`}>
            Click here for past CRA puzzles and to check previous answers
          </p>
        </a>

        <a
          href="https://www.coey.au/kin"
          className="group rounded-lg border border-transparent px-5 py-4 transition-colors hover:border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:dark:border-neutral-700 hover:dark:bg-neutral-800/30"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          <h2 className={`mb-3 text-2xl font-semibold`}>
            More fun{' '}
            <span className="inline-block transition-transform group-hover:translate-x-1 motion-reduce:transform-none">
              -&gt;
            </span>
          </h2>
          <p className={`m-0 max-w-[30ch] text-sm opacity-50`}>
            Here is another - completely different - game to play to challenge your mind.
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

Here's the `getDataFromGoogleSheets` function, (from the file `google_access.tsx`, see image of directory below):

```
export async function getDataFromGoogleSheet({ row = 1, column = 1 } = {}) {
    try {
        const auth = await google.auth.getClient({ scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'] });
        const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });
        const range = `Sheet1!A${row}:C${column}`;
        console.log("Requesting range:" + range);
        const response = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
            spreadsheetId: process.env.SHEET_ID,
            range,
        });

        const data = response.data.values[0];

        return {
            props: {
                data,
            },
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data from Google Sheet:', error);
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch data from Google Sheet');
    }
}
```

Here's the directories:

[image: a directory tree showing the main directory CRApuzzle containing .next, app, node_modules, pages, and public folders. page.tsx is in the app folder. google_access.tsx is the only file in the pages folder.]

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to put the columns in the webpage I would suggest reviewing what data type the API is returning, for example, if it is an array, you should either map it to a component in your page, or stringify it just to see if it is working.

Secondly, you should move your function to another directory called 'src' instead of putting it in the pages directory, as that is used similarly to the App router to generate a page (Hence the red squigly lines under the pages directory and your file with the function in it.)